# ASP.NET MVC EF with MySQL required .dll and their usage?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

When I try to connect my VS2013 with Update 3 to MySQL database with ADO.NET EF6, I found a MySQL - [**BUG**](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?174,601264,601264)

After I successfully able to connect **manually** with MySQL database, now I have 6 `.dll` installed.

1. [MySql.Data](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/)
2. [MySql.Web](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Web/)
3. [MySql.Data.Entity](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.Entity/)
4. [MySql.ConnectorNET.Data](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.ConnectorNET.Data/)
5. [MySql.ConnectorNET.Entity](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.ConnectorNET.Entity/)
6. [MySql.ConnectorNET.Web](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.ConnectorNET.Web/)

I didn't use MySQL with ASP.NET sites before, so I tried to find on web that which `.dll` is at least required to use MySQL with ADO.NET EF and also the purpose of each `.dll` but I didn't able to find anything.

**My question is -** I want know the required `.dll` to use MySQL with MVC Entity Framework and what is the use & purpose of each one `.dll` that I mentioned above and also what is the difference between MySql.Data.Entity vs MySql.ConnectorNET.Entity and what about MySql.ConnectorNET.Web?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Entity Framework 6 you will need to reference the following `.dll's`:

```
MySql.Data
MySql.Data.Entity.EF6
MySql.Web
```

You may want to install [MySQL for Visual Studio 1.1.4](https://blogs.oracle.com/MySqlOnWindows/entry/mysql_for_visual_studio_12) that has some bug fixes for VS 2103.

I use version 6.8.3.0 for my VS 2013 Update 2 ASP sites with MySql.

Check out the articles [here](http://www.nzmk.com/Blogs/BlogsView/tabid/83/EntryId/8/MVC5-EF6-ContosoUniversity-code-first-approach-using-MySQL.aspx) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/788357/How-to-set-up-application-using-ASP-NET-Identity-w) for infomation on how to setup Web.config etc. to use Entity Framework with MySql.

Documentation for MySql Connectors can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/index.html).

Comment: When I tried with these 3 the [BUG](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?174,601264,601264) occured. At least I need the [MySql.ConnectorNET.Entity](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.ConnectorNET.Entity/) to connect with MySQL EF6 and I also want to know the use of each one `.dll`???

Comment: How did you install MySql server on your development machine? Did you install MySQL for Visual Studio 1.1.4?

Comment: I installed the [MySQL Installer 5.6.20](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/) on my windows machine.

Comment: If you installed the full 248.2MB package, you should not have an issue. Check your Web.config settings by looking at the second article above. The .dll documentation should be found in http://dev.mysql.com

Comment: Thanks for help but I want to know - What is the difference between MySql.Data.Entity vs MySql.ConnectorNET.Entity and why it's not working without MySql.ConnectorNET.Entity for me and what about MySql.ConnectorNET.Web???

Comment: My Web.config settings are based on by this [MySQL LINK](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-asp-roles.html)

Comment: Not sure of the differences but you will surely need MySql.Data.Entity.EF6. Try and download the source code in the 2nd article and see if the settings work for you.

Answer (score 1):

**Now I've found my solution:**

1. The required .dll to use MySQL with MVC Entity Framework are -

   ```
   MySql.Data
   MySql.Data.Entity
   MySql.Web
   ```
2. The difference between MySql.XXXX vs MySql.ConnectorNET.XXXX is the version 6.8.3 to 6.8.3.2
3. `MySql.Data` is required for using MySQL Database.
4. `MySql.Data.Entity` is required for using Entity Framework with MySQL Database.
5. `MySql.Web` is required for using [ASP.NET Membership and Role Provider with MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-asp-roles.html).
6. I think the [**BUG**](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?174,601264,601264) appeared because MySql.ConnectorNET.Entity is the lastest version instead of MySql.Data.Entity.